# C Does passing argument from function to function will copy it's content?

Tags: c, stack, embedded

The code:

```
//function prototype
void efg(int x);
//mother functioon
abc()
{
int a=1;
efg(a);
}
```

When `efg` is executing, changing `x` is not changing `a` then we have a copy of `a`. But what if we dont want a copy to use memory efficiently?

One way is to pass the `a`'s pointer `&a`.

I have som constrants:

1. Don't want to pass anything. Since I have about 20 variable.
2. Don't want it's pointer's. I want direct access to it.
3. Dont want to being globally static.
4. Reluctant to use Heap dynamic allocation since it's embedded also it forces me to use pointer's instead of direct access.

I want my sub function (`efg`) be able to use the mother function's variable (`a` in `abc`) .It means `efg` being able to access `a` directly. Why not? Also I want `a` being being freed after `abc` execution finishes, since in the way explained the variables are in stack they will freed after function finishes.

The exact problem is: sub_functions initiate some structures in the memory. After sub function is finihed its job (CPU returns to mother function) the memories must be staying untouched untill the mother function finishes (CPU return to main) and here the memory must being freed.

My best dreaming solution is to use extern variable declare to use mother function stack in sub routine.

Comment: You need to pass a pointer to `efg` if you want it to modify the value of the original `a`. There's nothing to free since there is no dynamic allocation. `a` will simply go out of scope at the end of `abc`.

Comment: There's isn't anything to manually free. When the function ends the local variables will be cleaned up. Perhaps you made your example too simple? It's hard to know what you're looking for.

Comment: @RetiredNinja For example some attribute or specifier to make variable gloal inside it's scope. But I want it to not making it static. And feel reluctant to using it's pointer.

Comment: What you want and what C provides seem to be quite different.

Comment: What you are asking for is "pass by reference". However, the C language **does not** support "pass by reference". The C "work-around" is to "pass a reference to the object" which basically means "pass a pointer to the object". Or to put it short: What you are asking is not supported by C

Comment: @SupportUkraine They could provide two kind of passing, doesn't it? :-( or two kind of auto variables, one limited to scpoe (pass by value) another static in scope (pass by reference).

Comment: @SupportUkraine Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249213/discussion-between-mohammadsdtmnd-and-support-ukraine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Don't want to pass anything. Since I have about 20 variable.

I hope you aren't planning to pass 20 variables to a function or you need to start placing related variables together in the same struct. If you have 20 variables total, well what does that have to do with anything?

> Don't want it's pointer's. I want direct access to it.

That doesn't make any sense without a rationale *why* you want direct access. Indirect access vs direct access is such a minor performance difference that one shouldn't even bother considering it. Manually optimize when you actually have real time constraints or bottlenecks, don't optimize just for the heck of it.

If you worry about performance, then one sensible approach is to use small functions with internal linkage that will surely be inlined by the compiler. Note however that inlining is an execution speed over program size optimization.

> Dont want to being globally static.

That's kind of contradicting, I assume you mean declared with `static` storage class specified but declared at file scope. Using such variables may or may not be valid design depending on use-case. For single core embedded systems, there's not really anything wrong with such variables.

> Reluctant to use Heap dynamic allocation since it's embedded also it forces me to use pointer's instead of direct access.

Yes heap allocation should be avoided for multiple reasons in such systems. I wrote a summary of all the problems here: [Why should I not use dynamic memory allocation in embedded systems?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/286121) However, avoiding indirect access is not a valid reason.

---

> The exact problem is: sub_functions initiate some structures in the memory. After sub function is finihed its job (CPU returns to mother function) the memories must be staying untouched untill the mother function finishes (CPU return to main) and here the memory must being freed.

So that's solved by declaring the variables as local, on the stack, then pass its address to the other function. If you don't want any other part of the program to touch that memory in the meantime, then simply refrain from writing code which does that...

Summary: don't state a bunch of ultimatums out of the blue, for which you can't sensibly argue in favour for or against. It's pretty clear that you have limited experience of program design, let alone manual code optimization. So for now the best thing you can do is to write code as readable as possible, following well-known best practices (const correctness, private encapsulation etc etc). Because readable code also tends to be efficient, bug-free code. Whereas needlessly contrived and complex code tends to be slow, buggy and hard to maintain.

Comment: My consideration here is memorry efficiency, Think of it: my exact solution here is pass by reference, though I dont want to pass, we could (In dream) declare mother's function auto variables in subroutine with `extern` before it. I know why it is forbidded, since subroutines don't know where they will be used. They can not be certain about validation of those stack variables I wanted to extern them in subroutine. As you told not passing 20 argument must be done through struct and my solution can be work around:

Comment: You can do like: void efg(int *px) {int x = *px; // code using/modifying x.... and then; *px = x; return;} and call it like efg(&a); but the "danger" is to forget the *px = x; part before returning.... by @SupportUkraine

Comment: But instead of that workaround and pointer pass is C++ pass by reference and the struct pass of all variables.

Comment: Thanks for extensive answer. Note here my affort in this question was to manage memory dynamically through stack instead of heap.

Comment: in time of executing `abc`, `a` is static for `efg`, doesn't it? it exist all over the execution of `efg`. Since you have high embedded experience I'm interested on you comment about this discussion. Note my talk and write are not completely exact maybe need more effort to understanding concepts in my mind, sorry. thank you so much.

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd "but the "danger" is to forget the *px = x; part before returning" That's nonsense, the programmer must have some sort of minimum awareness of what they are doing - no amount of best coding practices can fix the programmer. Otherwise you might as well say "the danger is that the programmer forgets to implement the function" and that's essentially the same thing.

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd "But instead of that workaround and pointer pass is C++ pass by reference and the struct pass of all variables" No it isn't, C++ references are just "syntactic sugar" around pointer passing. Different syntax, same machine code in the end.

Comment: "in time of executing abc, a is static for efg, doesn't it?" If you mean to say that it is valid then yes, any local variable is valid until the program reaches the `}` of the block where the variable was declared.